# SQL query to select from a multiple to single and single to single relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to create a role based access where a User can have one or more UserGroups and that maps to Roles.

```
I have the following tables:
```

UserRole

```
     CREATE TABLE [User_Role](
            [id] [int] NOT NULL,
            [name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

UserGroup:

```
    CREATE TABLE User_Group(
        [id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [name] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
        [roleId] [int] NOT NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Scenario 1 expected results:
User has userG1, userG2. The query returns role1, role2 
 `"select * from Role where Role.id=UserGroup.roleId" should be ok.`

Scenario 2:
User has userG1, userG3. The query should return, role1, role3, and rol4 since the user has userG1 AND userG3.

> I am thinking the following solution:
>   Mapping table Role_UserGroup_Map -

```
 CREATE TABLE Role_UserGroup_Map(
            [roleId] [int] NOT NULL,
            [userGroups] [varchar](255) NOT NULL
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The mapping will contain all combinations of userGroup to Role. And my SQL will check for "like" with AND to return the Roleid

I am not sure how to represent the data and query the data to get "combined group into Roles". If someone can help with idea for table/data placement and the query that would be very helpful!

The goal is so that if I add any new UserGroups, it will be mapped to a new Role AND it could be mapped to existing Roles in combination of other UserGroup access if the User has them.

Comment: Sample data, as formatted `text`, or as DDL and DML statements, and expected results will really help here. Can you post them please?

Comment: Create a bridge table UserRoleMap with RoleID and UserGroupID, which will be a one to many. Eliminate roleId in UserGroup table.

Comment: how do i differentiate between which combination of UserGroupID to RoleID? For example:
roleID1: groupID1
roleID2: groupID2
roleID1:groupID4+groupID5?
roleID1:groupID6+groupID7?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask